# Why python yahoo finance scraping is printing same value continuously?

Tags: python, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


while True:
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ETH-USD?p=ETH-USD"

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    price = soup.find_all(
        'div', {'class': 'D(ib) Mend(20px)'})[0].find().text
    # return price

    print("Ethereum Price :" + price)
    time.sleep(1)
```

why this print the same value continuously? it should be change as I know, but its not happening

Answer (score 0):

I think the `requests.get()` receives the cached version somehow (could be possible cause) and this can be overcome by using `Cache-Control` header in your request

Try this

```py
requests.get(url, headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})
```

Comment: no, :( still it's same

Comment: Have you tried increasing the sleep timer?

Comment: Ethereum Price :4,127.13
Ethereum Price :4,127.13
Ethereum Price :4,127.13
Ethereum Price :4,127.13
Ethereum Price :4,127.13
Ethereum Price :4,127.13
Ethereum Price :4,127.13
Ethereum Price :4,127.13
Ethereum Price :4,127.13
Ethereum Price :4,127.13
Ethereum Price :4,127.13

this is the result when i change the time to 2 seconds

Comment: Is your system's time up to date? That could be a possibility  Or Yahoo Finance is not that much real-time 